# How to capture an event when $compile completes Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code...

```
var html = angular.element("<div><h1>{{var}}</h1></div>");
var compiled = $compile(html.contents())(scope);
setTimeout(function(){
  dialogService.openModal(compiled[0].outerHTML);
},100);
```

If you will notice I need to use a timeout while the compile is processed. I tried using $timeout $evalAsync and $interval none seem to exactly mimic this behavior.

Can someone help me better understand why those other patterns do not work but this does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use watch instead and destroy it as soon as the compile is done (the watch method returns destroyer that invoked as function destroys the watch - if that makes sense)

```
var html = angular.element("<div><h1>{{var}}</h1></div>");
var compiled = $compile(html.contents())(scope);
destroyWatch = $scope.$watch(
  function (){
    return compiled;
  },
  function (newValue, oldValue){
    if(newValue !== oldValue){
      dialogService.openModal(compiled[0].outerHTML);
      destroyWatch()
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Could you please explain how does this work? Why it is different from using timeout?